# Keyboard layout for single window

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have installed elementary OS Loki. I cannot find the option which allows me to have different keyboard layouts for different windows. Will this option be enabled or how to figure out with it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this option doesn't work on Freya & Loki now.

Follow the progress of fixes you can [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1444519), also you can [post bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/37962080-allow-different-layouts-for-individual-windows-does-not-work) for this bug.

Comment: Also this [Github issue](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/180) , updated for Juno